# Is it possible to run a docker registry for gitlab externally on a remote host?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I'm just curious if there's a chance to move out the gitlab registry to a different host? I can see, that it is possible to move the storage to another place, but what about the service itself?

I just want to run the registry on another place but want to make use of the authentication and the UI features of gitlab to manage it. May be this is not possible, but please someone shed some light on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you can disable the bundled registry and run a registry yourself, while still using GitLab's authentication and UI.

GitLab's built-in registry is basically just a deployment of the [Docker Registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/). You can run it, or another compatible registry, and then configure GitLab to use it as described here: [Disable Container Registry but use GitLab as an auth endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/container_registry.html#disable-container-registry-but-use-gitlab-as-an-auth-endpoint).

Comment: I'm going to test drive this in the cloud. Much appreciated, thanks.